# Evaluating $\sec\big(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\big).\sec\big(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\big)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Evaluate $$\sec\big(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\big).\sec\big(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\big)$$

This can be evaluated as
$$
\sec\big(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\big).\sec\big(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\big)=\frac{1}{\cos\big(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\big).\cos\big(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\big)}\\
=\frac{1}{\cos^2\frac{\pi}{4}-\sin^2x}=\frac{2}{1-2\sin^2x}=2\sec2x
$$
But, when I try the following by making use of the formula $2\cos x\cos y=\cos(x+y)+\cos(x-y)$,
$$
\sec\big(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\big).\sec\big(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\big)=\frac{2}{2\cos\big(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\big).\cos\big(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\big)}\\
=\frac{2}{\cos\frac{\pi}{2}+\cos2x}=\frac{2}{\text{not defined} +\cos2x}
$$

Why do I get such a problem in my second attempt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why will cos $\pi/2$ not be defined?

Comment: Perhaps this "answer" would make sense as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: ohhk. thankx ans sorry. will take care from next time.

Comment: It seems that the OP is thinking of the denominator as individual terms $(2/\cos(\pi/2))$ and $(2/\cos(2x))$.  Perhaps you can explain that misconception to improve your answer.